# Автоматическое растягивание элементов WPF под размер родителя (растягивание внутри ListBox)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть `ListBox` выводящий список заказов

```
<ListBox Name="orderList" Margin="23,49,44,30">       
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="5" Background="Yellow">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="2"
                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Text="{Binding Path=Good.title}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="2" Text=" Цена: " />
                        <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Path=Good.price}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="2" Text=" Количество: " />
                        <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Path=count}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Margin="2"
                                Click="Button_Click"
                                Content="Удалить"
                                Tag="{Binding}" />
                        <Button Margin="2"
                                Click="Button_Click"
                                Content="Редактировать"
                                Tag="{Binding}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Идея в том, чтобы описание заказа и кнопки "Редактировать" и "Удалить" выравнивать по разным краям. Однако вмещающий элемент `Grid` становится ровно такой ширины, чтобы вместить в себя элементы, не больше поэтому в итоге все вместе слеплено. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы `Grid` был по размеру `ListBox` ? Думал сделать так: `Width="{Binding ElementName=orderList, Path=Width}"`, но не работает,если не задать `ListBox` ширину явно, и еще из-за отступов появляются полосы прокрутки снизу (фактическая ширина больше родителя становится). Как быть?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Задайте у `ListBox` свойство `HorizontalContentAlignment`:

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ... />
```

В шаблоне `ListBoxItem` выравнивание `ContentPresenter` определено через `HorizontalContentAlignment` родительского списка.